# spring-data-elasticsearch - @Field mapping type ignored when @Id annotated on the same field

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, mapping

```
@Document(indexName = "opportunity_data", type = "opportunities", createIndex = false)
@Setting(settingPath = "/search/settings.json")
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"id"}, allowGetters = true, allowSetters = false)
public class OpportunityVo extends AbstractGenericVo<Opportunity> {

  @Id
  @Field(type = FieldType.Long)
  private Long opportunityId;

  @Field(type = FieldType.Long)
  private Long prospectId;
  @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
  private String prospectName;
}
```

[mapping to keyword snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gG3kT.png)

the `opportunityId` above is mapped to `keyword` other than the `long` type. Anyone knows how to map the **opportunityId** to `long` type when `@Id` annotated at the same time since I'd like to do `stats` metrics aggregation on this property?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Stats aggregation can be only applied to numerics. Change the mappings works fine. But @Id will be mapped to keyword , still no luck.